# How NOT to block control of a button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I dont know if I formulated the question correctly but let me explain.
To make things simple, I added to buttons to a WPF. the Button start has the following code

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        while (r ==false)
        {
            lstBox.Items.Add(x++);
        }
    }
```

and button stop :

```
    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        r = true;
    }
```

" r " being a global boolean variable.

Whenever a click on Start, I can no longer click the Stop button.

do you know how to make the button stop active or "clickeable" regardless of what is being executed?

Comment: You are blocking the ui thread because you are looping infinitely on it. You might want to consider using the Task parallel library for this or the background worker class.

Comment: I will look into the background worker class. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delegate void Work();

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    new Work(WorkOne).BeginInvoke(null, null);
}

private void WorkOne()
{
    int x = 0;
    while (r == false)
    {
        listBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>{ listBox.Items.Add(x++); }));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
    }
}

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        r = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not as trivial as it seems. you need to free the wpf thread of your looping so it can process other events and react on other buttons.there is a lot learn there to achieve it.
google  either backgoundworker class or task async await (for vs2012 and newer). but there is also an alternative and simple hack: google windows forms doevents() you can call it from wpf too. but this will get very difficult to maintain once your program becomes more complex.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I actually wanted some direction and you have done just that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your stuck in an infinite loop. while (r==false) is always running, not allowing you to use the stop button. You need some sort of exit on your looping structure.